# the condition has length > 1 not on Linux

Tags: r

I understand why this error happens here:

```
parse_spec = function(ttype, spec = NA) {
  ...
  if (is.na(spec)) {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

When spec can be one element or list. So my quickfix is:

```
parse_spec = function(ttype, spec = NA) {
  ...
  if (length(spec) == 1 && is.na(spec)) {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

However, the error occurred only when I posted it to winbuilder: https://win-builder.r-project.org/upload.aspx
I didn't get it on my Linux machine with R:

```
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02) -- "Feather Spray"
Copyright (C) 2018 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
```

Why isn't the error thrown on Linux? Would it better to use NULL as default argument?

Comment: Not an answer to the question but note that if `length(spec) > 1` then the use of `&&` may be a problem, R will only consider the first element of the vector.

Comment: For default arguments, I waffle between `missing(spec)` (i.e., no default value) and a default of `NULL`. There are times when (to me) a value of `NA` is meaningful and different than a value of `NULL`. (I don't play the game of `!missing(spec) && is.null(spec)`, as they tends to get rather circular/confusing.) Lately I've been leaning more towards explicit defaults of `=NULL`, that way the test is always singular and simple: `is.null(spec)`, no need to guard against vectors. However, if you prefer `=NA`, then you can always try `any(is.na(spec))`, though the logic is a little different.

Comment: Based on the documentation (check `?\`&&\``), it should work without issue.  It might be a bug, but I don't have a windows environment to test on.